# Boot failed, continue to look for media

Tags: windows, raid, boot, bios

I have a new server that runs a RAID 1. I've had it off for about a month and I turn it back on and I am getting "boot failed, continue to look for Boot Media" and it just loops.

Did my RAID die or something? :(

This is an HP ProLiant MicroServer GEN 7.

I had Windows Server 2012 DATACENTER running on it.

EDIT:

- I've tried all the hard connections. Drives are plugged in.
- I've gone into the raid array configurations and it shows the drives and the raid array

Comment: If the RAID died it should show something during the boot process to that affect.  It appears that it cannot find the array though.  What have you done to troubleshoot this?  I'm afraid your question could be downvoted and closed for lack of detail or research on your own, so you should include steps you've already taken, screenshots (camera phone if need be), etc.

Comment: POST seeing the array and Windows seeing the array are two different things. Is the proper RAID controller driver installed in Windows? Are the boot devices/options/sequence configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the SAS connector (the big connector for the hard drives). Check it's plugged in and remove/reinsert if not sure.
[source: http://www.avforums.com/forums/networking-nas/1636476-hp-proliant-microserver-n40l-owners-thread-part-3-a-26.html#758 ]